# Prove that in the half plane $\{x>0\}$, ω is the differential of a function.

Tags: differential-topology

Define a 1-form $ω$ on the punctured plane $R^2-\{0\}$ by

$ω(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2 }dy $

a)  Calculate $∫_Cω$ for any circle C of radius r around the origin

b) Prove that in the half plane $\{x>0\}$, ω is the differential of a function.

c)Why isn’t $ω$ the differential of a function globally on $R^2-{0}$?

for a), it's easy, just use the polar coordinate, and I got the result is $2\pi$

for c), it's also easy, because if $ω$ is the differential of a function globally on $R^2-{0}$ by Stoke's theorem

$$\int_{C=\partial (R^2-0)} \omega =\int_{R^2-0} d\omega$$

but $d\omega=0$ so

$$\int_{C=\partial (R^2-0)} \omega =\int_{R^2-0} d\omega=0$$

but from part a)

$$\int_{C=\partial (R^2-0)} \omega =2\pi \not =0$$

for part b), the book told me to use $arctan(\frac y x)$. But I'm not sure what they mean by that.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. You do agree on the half plane that $\omega$ is the differential of $\arctan(y/x)$, yes? (Nice problem btw.)

Comment: oh, so they just give away the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Your argument for (c) doesn't work, because $/omega$ isn't defined on all of $B^2$.

Comment: There's still a problem with your edited version of (c): $\mathbb R^2 - \{0\}$ is not a manifold with boundary, nor is it compact, nor is $\omega$ compactly supported, so Stokes's theorem doesn't apply to it.